# Providers for running Javascript and Solidity 24x7

Tags: solidity, ide

I am about to deploy Solidity contract onto Arbitrum mainnet but instead of running the associated JavaScript from my laptop which makes regular call outs to the deployed solidity back-end contract, I would prefer paying a small monthly fee with likes of Azure, AWS or equivalent that offers this capability so I can run it on 24x7 directly as a Cloud SaaS rather from my laptop.

Would appreciate if you could make some suggestions and recommendations for appropriate SaaS providers that could offer this execution runtime at affordable price.

Also, some sort of control dashboard that I could regularly log into to stop/restart and perform issue diagnostics whenever they arise, performance stats, etc.

Any ideas/clues?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You need to interact with Arbitrum's blockchain trough a full node, and you basically have 2 main options to get one:

1. Pay a node provider (SASS). You can choose one from this official list. They provide you with an API-Key and a node endpoint URL: https://developer.arbitrum.io/node-running/node-providers
2. You can set up and manage your own dedicated node, in a Virtual Machine from any Cloud Provider you are familiar with, following this official guide: https://developer.arbitrum.io/node-running/running-a-node

Answer (score 0):

Gelato can do that for you. They have automation services that you can define onchain. Then you just have to fund your wallet and Gelato will execute based on your defined criteria (e.g. once per x hour, or when certain on chain criteria like prices are met)

https://www.gelato.network/automate